# How to create some windows, dialogs ... in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I want to create some windows, dialog for my game. I mean: when I press the specific key, a window disappear (option dialog) and I can set keys for tasks, reduce mouse's sensitive...
And how to create line text which I can use mouse to click it to open window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is a GUI (Graphical User Interface). Since XNA is not a game engine, but a game framework. You have to build a lot of these kind of important concepts yourself. Luckily, there is a huge community for XNA and there are several GUI frameworks which you can include in your game.

I found this [list of GUI's](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/15274.aspx) by google-ing for XNA GUI